# Advantages/Disadvantages of Header Files

Tags: java, c++, c, header

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using header files in a language like C or C++ verses a language like Java?  I think classes should be designed from the outside in, so it is nice to have header files and not have to wade through implementation details.  However, then again, each function declaration is duplicated across two files.  If C and C++ were invented today would they use header files?  Is this mechanism outdated or necessary?

Comment: [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29) ... but header files allow me to be lazy and not write all the declarations (and types and enums and defines and macros) all over "plain" C source files

Comment: Java classes (at least at my school) usually are defined in one file.  C, C++, and objective C classes are usually defined in two files.

Comment: Java uses two files as well, but calls one of them `interface`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons to use interfaces in Java -- as Bo Persson stated just before I did. :)

Comment: Technically, the _declaration_ isn't being duplicated.  The _declaration_ is in one file and the _definition_ in another.  Java just allows implicit declarations.  Whether it's useful to split them is the real question.  It's never strictly necessary, but can be handy if you want to provide someone (like a library user) with the declaration but not the definition.

Comment: Nobody would invent header files today.

Comment: @David - Right, nobody in his right mind would invent C today. It was done at a time when these guys tried to force a language into a machine that took up half the room, but only contained 24 kB RAM and used 10 chars/second terminals. [Ken and Den](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/picture.html)

Comment: @Bo I agree. You have to judge something in context. C was clearly a wonderful solution to a particular problem and clearly still has its merits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from a related [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx) by Eric Lippert, who puts it very well:

> I would have asked the equivalent
>   question *why does C++ need header
>   files*? Header files seem like a huge
>   potential point of failure; all the
>   time I edit C++ code and change the
>   signature of a method; if I forget to
>   update the header file, then the code
>   doesn’t compile and often gives some
>   cryptic error message. Hopefully this
>   large cost actually buys you
>   something.
>
> It buys the compiler writer one thing,
>   and the user one thing.
>
> What it buys the user is that you can
>   compile each individual “cpp” file
>   into a “obj” file independently,
>   provided that you have all the
>   necessary headers. All the information
>   necessary to generate the bodies that
>   are in a given cpp file can be gleaned
>   from the set of headers. This means
>   that the build system can recompile
>   just those cpp files that changed,
>   provided that no header changed.
>
> What it buys the compiler writer is
>   that every file can be compiled in
>   “one pass”. Because every type and
>   method *declaration* is processed before
>   its first *usage*, the compiler can
>   simply start from the top of the file,
>   pull in all the included headers, and
>   proceed from the top down, spitting
>   out the obj file as it goes, never
>   having to go back and revisit
>   something its seen already.

This is in contrast to languages such as C# (about which the blog post is) and Java, which is a pretty close relative.

Comment: The interesting thing about this is what it buys the user. It allows the user to re-compile file by file. But this is really only needed because of the extravagant compile/link times of C and especially C++.   So to my mind it's really all about the compiler and the poor developer is the 2nd class citizen.

Comment: Java is a close relative of C#. Java is the father of C#.

Comment: @irreputable: That made me laugh. It's also an opinion I share.

Comment: I don't think the first point is really legitimate.  If you replace `header` with `class file` you can easily get that behaviour in Java. Regarding C#, you can distribute a class over several files so that might restrict what the compiler is able to do, but I'd still be surprised if you couldn't get something to the same effect.

Comment: @CurtainDog but wouldn't that require recompilation every time the .class file changed, even if that change wasn't in the interface?  Are there really no disadvantages to gleaning the interface from object files and no using header files?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree, and one of the reasons compilation is so slow is that many headers get compiled over and over in each compilation unit; a problem that doesn't exist in languages like Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's still a good idea to separate interface and implementation. But it doesn't have to be physical separation. In Java you can see the interface from javadoc. Java IDEs usually can display API structures, and they can fold blocks. There is no compelling reasons that require physical separation. C was invented decades ago so we don't need to pick on it.

Comment: Also, C++ headers are not at all about separating interface and implementation.  They can contain lots of implementation details, such as private class members (both data and functions) and bodies of inline and template functions.  I've always considered headers an artifact of how the compiler is implemented, rather than a useful feature.

Answer (score -2):

Briefly, in C or C++ header files allow different files to share common definitions or declarations.

In Java everything is an object, so there's no concept of sharing anything except objects. Each object is one file; if you want to access the object, you import the file.